# Extract Static Acceleration from MPU6050 using Formula

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, mpu6050, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to implement a research paper for my project and there is a formula which I am failing to interpret:

[image: Formula]

According to the research paper, we extract the static acceleration component for each axis µ, (i=X, Y, Z) by using a running mean filter (the formula), where t is time index, win_size is the window size, and ,∗ is the acceleration data, respectively.

The research paper using MPU6050 to implement this formula. My question is how do I calculate these values using MPU6050. I am currently using [MPU6050_Light.h](https://github.com/rfetick/MPU6050_light/blob/master/documentation_MPU6050_light.pdf) library to calculate acceleration values and I have no idea where to move from here.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could change the limits to `0 to win_size - 1` so that they are compatible with C arrays. Then cycle around the array putting a new `float` into it at the current index while updating the sum and rolling average. Then update the index.

Comment: Are you asking about how to read the acceleration from the MPU6050? Or are you asking about how to compute a [running average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)?

Comment: @EdgarBonet, Thank You for your reply. You have nudged me in the right direction by telling me about running average. I didn't know that this formula was of calculating running average since nothing was mentioned in the research paper.